# Is it safe to add a new field to meta_value field?

Tags: post-meta, meta-value, guids

I'm trying to offload Wordpress images from my web server. I've successfully moved everything over to `Amazon AWS` and have a syncing mechanism in place that uploads new images to AWS. Now I would like to store a flag somewhere that indicates whether the image has been synced so my custom theme can pick the correct path. I was thinking adding that flag to the `wp_postmeta` table, as part of the `meta_value` serialized object.

Is that a safe technique? What are the chances this value gets overwritten and lost?

Additionally, I assume the `guid` field `wp_posts` shouldn't be updated with the full path to the image on AWS? That could be a solution as well.

Comment: `guid` doesn't affect the image URL, it is just used as a unique identifier. It could be random gobbledygook and as long as it is unique it wouldn't make a difference. It should be safe to use postmeta as long as you aren't using any plugins that would potentially completely overwrite all postmeta associated with an attachment - no plugins I am familiar with would do so, just mentioning what you would need to check on. Most plugins use `update_post_meta` which adds or updates if a particular postmeta key is found, so use a unique `meta_key` and you should be safe.

Comment: @WebElaine Awesome, that's what I wanted to double check. Maybe post your comment as an answer and I'll pick it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`guid` doesn't affect the image URL, it is just used as a unique identifier. It could be random gobbledygook and as long as it is unique it wouldn't make a difference. It should be safe to use postmeta as long as you aren't using any plugins that would potentially completely overwrite all postmeta associated with an attachment - no plugins I am familiar with would do so, just mentioning what you would need to check on. Most plugins use `update_post_meta` which adds or updates if a particular postmeta key is found, so use a unique `meta_key` and you should be safe.

Comment: Does that mean I should ignore wp_posts of the attachments type for my syncing strategy and solely concentrate on what I find in table wp_postmeta?

Comment: It depends on what data you need and what you're doing with that data. `wp_postmeta` probably contains all the information you need to identify the correct URL, alt text, and image dimensions.

Comment: I need the image data so I can upload all sizes to Amazon AWS.